# Property 'selectedvalue' is used before its initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to share the date from service to another component through BehaviorSubject but getting the above error.

```
public content = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.selectedvalue);
public share = this.content.asObservable();
selectedvalue: Meal[] = [];

loadSubCategoriesFood(name: string): Observable<{ meals: Meal[] }> {
  return this.http
    .get<{ meals: Meal[] }>(
      this.recipies.listofsubcategories + 'filter.php?i=' + name
    )
    .pipe(
      tap((resultcategory) => {
        this.selectedvalue = resultcategory?.meals;
      })
    );
}
```

My another Component :

This is where I am subscribing the service.

```
export class CategorypageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public categoryfood: HomepageService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const getSharedValue = this.categoryfood.share.subscribe((x) =>
      console.log(x)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `selectedValue` does not appear in the code you shared

Comment: For some reasons I'm unable to add this code, stackoverflow is complaining about too much code

Comment: please edit the question to add this code

Comment: @tobias.S can you check now I have added the code

Comment: can you switch the order around? So initialize `selectedvalue` first, then place the `content` initialization

Comment: Can you say it more precise, I didn't get you actually

Comment: I did but my array value is comming empty in the console.log of the category component where I am subscribing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just passing `selectedvalue` to be `BehaviourSubject` *once*. The updates to `selectedValue` will *not be seen* by the `BehaviourSubject`.

Use the `.next()` method to push changes to the `BehaviourSubject`.

```
public content = new BehaviorSubject<Meal[]>([]);
public share = this.content.asObservable();

loadSubCategoriesFood(name: string): Observable<{ meals: Meal[] }> {
  return this.http
    .get<{ meals: Meal[] }>(
      this.recipies.listofsubcategories + 'filter.php?i=' + name
    )
    .pipe(
      tap((resultcategory) => {
        this.content.next(resultcategory?.meals)
      })
    );
  }
}
```

In that case, you don't need `selectedvalue` anymore.

Comment: Yeah I did that but my array value is coming empty in the category component where I am subscribing, am I missing something ?

Comment: @TerryC - ok so the error is gone? But the array is still empty. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yeah exactly, did I initialized the this.selectedvalue in the right way or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @TerryC - I think I got it. Check my edit.

Comment: Yeah this.selectedvalue = resultcategory?.meals; has the correct response which I need to pass it through another component, but I am getting empty array while subscribing.

Comment: worked like a charm, kindly excuse me, I'm relatively new to angular and these concepts, anyways Thanks @Tobias